# Error 404 after deploying and exposing Nginx pod

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have deployed and exposed Nginx with the following commands:

```
sudo kubectl create deployment mynginx1 --image=nginx
sudo kubectl expose deployment mynginx1 --type NodePort --port 8080
```

I access using `http://<master node IP>:<port>` or `http://172.17.135.42:31788`

But I am getting `Error 404`.  Help appreciated.

```
gtan@master:~$ kubectl get pods -owide -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       mynginx1-f544c49cb-g92w2         1/1     Running   0          3m19s   172.168.10.2    slave1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-92r4n         1/1     Running   0          7m56s   172.168.10.2    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-gc7tc         1/1     Running   0          7m56s   172.168.10.3    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running   0          8m6s    172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   0          8m6s    172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   0          8m6s    172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-24pwc      1/1     Running   3          4m58s   172.17.82.110   slave1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-q5qwg      1/1     Running   0          5m28s   172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-hf59b                 1/1     Running   0          4m58s   172.17.82.110   slave1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-r7pz6                 1/1     Running   0          7m56s   172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   0          8m5s    172.17.82.100   master   <none>           <none>
gtan@master:~$
```

```
gtan@master:~$ curl -IL http://172.17.82.100:30131
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.82.100 port 30131: Connection refused where "172.17.82.100" is the master node ip address.
```

```
gtan@master:~$ kubectl get services -o wide -A
NAMESPACE     NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
default       kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  15m   <none>
default       mynginx1     NodePort    10.102.106.240   <none>        80:30131/TCP             10m   app=mynginx1
kube-system   kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   15m   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

Answer (score 0):

The default nginx container port is `80` as you can see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx). Just change the container port from `8080` to `80` in your second command:

`sudo kubectl expose deployment mynginx1 --type NodePort --port 80`

and try to reach the service using the NodePort showed in the output of the command, for example:

```
$kubectl get svc

NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
mynginx1   NodePort   10.97.142.170   <none>        80:31591/TCP   8m9s
```

Altenatively, you can use this yaml spec to configure your pod and service:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

Testing using curl:

```
$ curl -IL http://localhost:31591
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.17.10
Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 10:05:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 14:19:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5e95c66e-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Also, I recommend you to reserve a time to take a look in these documentations pages:

[Kuberentes Concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/)

[Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping out.  Port 80 does not work as I got "connection refused" and hence I have had to use port "8080".  This is the response with curl:  godfrey@master:~$ curl -IL http://172.17.135.42:32640
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 04:32:34 GMT
Content-Length: 19

Comment: All nodes are built on Ubuntu's "mini.iso" image and are running in Hyperv.  One master and slave1 & slave2 nodes.  I also have minikube running in Hyperv and had no problems with "mynginx1" in minikube.  Only difference is that I used "kubectl create service nodeport mynginx1 --tcp=8080:80" to create the "mynginx1" service in minikube.  The output is: $ minikube service mynginx1
| default   | mynginx1 | 8080-80     | http://192.168.85.153:31706 |

Comment: I've tested the exact command in my lab and worked. So please add in your post the output of the commands `kubectl get svc` and `kubectl get pods`. Also, from where are you testing with curl? It's is a weird behavior, because the error 404 means your application answered. Make sure you don't have another app running on the same port. But again, port 8080 will not work in this case since nginx image runs in port 80.

Comment: godfrey@master:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          43h
mynginx1     NodePort    10.99.22.229   <none>        8080:32640/TCP   159m

Comment: godfrey@master:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mynginx1-f544c49cb-5d6vj   1/1     Running   0          168m
godfrey@master:~$

Comment: Testing the curl from master node ip address 172.17.135.42.

Comment: I agree its weird.  I used this web site to configure.  https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-kubernetes-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-18-10/.  My only service is "mynginx" created by me.  No other.

Comment: godfrey@master:~$ kubectl describe pods
Name:         mynginx1-f544c49cb-5d6vj
Node:         slave1/172.17.135.34
Start Time:   Wed, 13 May 2020 12:24:22 +0800
Labels:       app=mynginx1
              pod-template-hash=f544c49cb
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mynginx1-f544c49cb
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   docker://f38c9922146bf83084e28c659c7cca93f26cd0023704b8e7152f3705fde3137c
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:86ae264c3f4acb99b2dee4d0098c40cb8c46dcf9e1148f05d3a51c4df6758c12
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>

Comment: Executing describe pods, the "Port" & "Host Port" are empty.

Comment: Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  92s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mynginx1-54bbfc7866-g9xgr to minikube
  Normal  Pulling    92s   kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal  Pulled     58s   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "nginx"
  Normal  Created    57s   kubelet, minikube  Created container nginx
  Normal  Started    57s   kubelet, minikube  Started container nginx

Comment: The above events are listed using describe pods in minikube.  But in my master and slave nodes configuration, the events is listed as none.  That explains why nginx not created.  But still strange.

Comment: In describe services in the master and slave nodes config:  Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31562/TCP.  The ports are unset.  In minikube, the <unset> field is "80".

Comment: I tried using the create service command and the ports are set to 80 as shown by the describe service command.  However the curl command gives connection refused.

Comment: @GodfreyTan, I've updated my answer with a yaml spec for a nginx deployment + a service with NodePort configured. Please try to apply this yaml and see if you can curl the nginx. Make sure the pod are running before testing with the command `kubectl get pods -owide`.

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.135.42 port 31731: No route to host

Comment: kube-flannel-ds-amd64-tt5jf      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff 
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-tx8lw      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff

The above is what I discovered.

Comment: nginx-svs is running on slave2 node.

Comment: flannel is running fine on master node.  Then when I add the salve nodes to the cluster, there flannel in slave produces error.

Comment: @GodfreyTan, Since your problem is solved in minikube, I encourage you to create a new post in the stackoverflow to deal with this flannel pods issue.

Comment: Ok will do.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have solved flannel and exposed mynginx1 deployment.  I get:
godfrey@master:~$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE     IP                NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       mynginx1-69b4b469f6-b2lmh        0/1     ImagePullBackOff

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help.  I have solved both the flannel and nginx problem.  You may close the case.  Your CLI statements are absolutely correct.  Thank you.

Comment: @GodfreyTan, nice to hear that. Please consider accept and upvote my answer if you think it helped you. You can see how [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)

Comment: Hi, I think I spoke too soon.  Today I am getting connection refused on curl.  All flannel pods running fine but still connection problem.

Comment: And there are no logs in pod " mynginx1-f544c49cb-65d7t" for nginx.

Comment: @GodfreyTan please edit your first post and include: The output of the commands: `kubectl get pods -owide -A`, `kubectl get svc -A`, `kubectl get nodes`, `kubectl get ing`. Also, please describe in details how your environment was configured, if you have firewall rules configured or not. Please post the curl command you are using to test, and from where are you testing. Don't include theses information on comments to not broken the format, edit your original post.

Comment: Hi,  I can now do a successful curl to nginx.  I used the ip address of the slave node.  But yesterday I recall I used the master node ip address instead.  Is the ip address always the slave node ip address in curl?

Comment: No, you need to know where your pod is deployed. You can use `kubectl get pods -owide` and verify the column 'NODE'.

Comment: Hi, yes thanks.  Then I already solved the problem.  curl is working with http://<slave node ip>:nodeport.  Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the architecture of your setup? do you have worker node and master node on same machine?

check the nginx pod status with :

```
kubectl get pods
```

If the pod is running without issue then hit your worker machine IP with NodePort http:/Workernode_IP:Nodeport

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping out.  I have a master and two slave nodes:  172.17.135.42/34/35 respectively.  I used "curl --IL 172.17.135.34:32640" but got connection refused.  "mnginx1" service is running on 172.17.135.34 (slave1) and hence the pod is there.  Pod "mynginx1-f544c49cb-5d6vj" is on slave1.

Comment: Can you pls share the output of :

<kubectl get pods -o wide>


Also are you able to curl the pod_IP:80 on the worker node.

Comment: I am getting CrashLoopBackoff in flannel:
godfrey@master:~$ sudo  kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-tknhg         1/1     Running            0          4m54s
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-wnx2l         1/1     Running            0          4m53s
...
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-kbmdb      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          82s
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-mtfbp      0/1     Error              3          50s
...

Comment: flannel is running fine on master node. Then when I add the salve nodes to the cluster, there flannel in slave produces error.

Comment: Hi, I have solved the flannel problem: NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION INTERNAL-IP EXTERNAL-IP OS-IMAGE KERNEL-VERSION CONTAINER-RUNTIME master Ready master 39m v1.18.2 192.168.152.99 <none> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 4.15.0-99-generic docker://19.3.6 slave3 Ready <none> 34m v1.18.2 192.168.152.104 <none> Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 4.15.0-99-generic docker://19.3.6 curl -IL command gives connection refused.